# Multi-label Input to Single-label output

Tags: computer-vision, neural-network, convolution, deep-learning, caffe

Is there a research paper where inputs are multi-labeled but the output (classifier) is a single-labeled? Preferably in computer vision field.

Comment: May be better asked at https://stats.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: The question is quite vague :S What kind of input do you have? Could you give more information about it? (size/shape of the input, number of variables, type of variables, possible values for variables {if discrete}...)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear, but were you thinking of something like [similarity learning](http://lear.imag.fr/pubs/2007/NJ07/NJ07.pdf) where you are trying to learn a binary label ("same"/"not-same") given that the inputs are labeled with class labels (0..`L`)?

In computer vision you can find similar task for faces: given an input identity of faces you want a classifier to output (for a pair of faces) if they are of the same person or not. You can find more information regarding this research field on the web page of the [labeled faces in the wild](http://vis-www.cs.umass.edu/lfw/) benchmark.